# How to fetch the information from rss?

Tags: php, rss

Currently i am working on simplepie rss reader in which i have to fetch images present in `<content:encoded>` tag

```
http://devilsworkshop.org/feed
```

this is that url from which i have to fetch the images
i have written this code

```
<?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
                include_once('../my_done_work/simplepie.inc');
                $feed = new SimplePie();
                $feed->set_feed_url('http://devilsworkshop.org/feed');
                $feed->init();
                $feed->handle_content_type();


   function returnImage ($text)
{
        $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $pattern = "/<img[^>]+\>/i";
        preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
        $text = $matches[0];
        return $text;
}


function scrapeImage($text) 
{

        $pattern = '/src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)[\'" >]/'; 
        preg_match($pattern, $text, $link);
                $link = $link[1];
                $link = urlencode($link);

        return $link;

}
 $count = 0;
                $arrImg = array();
                $arrtitle = array();
                    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $kk=> $item) {
                        $feedDescription = $item->get_content();
                        $feedTitle = $item->get_title();
                        $image = returnImage($feedDescription);
                        $image = scrapeImage($image);
                        $image = urldecode($image);
                        $arrimg[$count] = $image;
                        $arrtitle[$count] = $feedTitle;
                       $jj = $kk+1;
                echo '<li><a href="#"><img src="' .$arrimg[$kk]. '" id="remove" ><span>'.$arrtitle[$kk].'</span></a></li>';

                        $count++;

                }

 ?>
```

but it doesn't give me all the images but only 10 of them.

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe that is because the feed only returns 10 items? If that is not the problem, can you describe exactly where image processing terminates and what the problem is?

Comment: no i have processed the rss so that it will take all the image tag and give me the src of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) instead of preg_match to get all regexp matches in a string.